# Running more than one if statement per time

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out with Javascript, so sorry if this is a simple question, couldn't find an answer on google or here.

I have a variable, after each time I press a button it adds a number to that function and runs a function that checks if the var number is between a certain number and another number and writes something if it is.

Problem is, I now have about 4 if statements that also overlap, but since they're if statements it just checks for the first true if and only prints out that one.

What if I want to print all the true statements? Is there a way to do that?

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var check = 0;
function numberchecker() {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Hello world";
            if ( check > 1 && check < 7 ) { document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Check 1";};
            if  ( check > 4 && check < 8 ) { document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Check 2"; } ;           
            if  ( check > 6 && check < 10 ) { document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Check 3";};
     console.log(check);
} ;

function addone() {check = check + 1; numberchecker()} ;
</script>

<p id="container"></p>
        <button onclick="addone()">Add One</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show any of your `if condition` ?

Comment: Dont use `if else if`, use separate `if` pattern for each.

Comment: Remove the `else` in between them. Use 4 `if`s (assuming none of them causes the enclosing function to return).

Comment: Please show us your code. Then it's much easier to help.

Comment: Where is your code? If you need help you have to show is what you have already written and what is not working the way you want it to be

Comment: Sorry here's the code

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you overwirte the result of the former assignment `document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ...`. The you get only the last check assignt.

(Small hint: curly brackets for [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) statements do not need a [semicolon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) behind the closing bracket.)

```js
var check = 0;

function numberchecker() {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "check: "+check+"<br>Hello world";
    if (check > 1 && check < 7) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<br>Check 1";
    }
    if (check > 4 && check < 8) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<br>Check 2";
    }
    if (check > 6 && check < 10) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<br>Check 3";
    }
    console.log(check);
}

function addone() {
    check = check + 1; numberchecker()
}
```

```html
<p id="container"></p>
<button onclick="addone()">Add One</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example add your text ("Check 1" or "Check 2" etc..) to an array using the array `push()` method when an if statement evaluates to true.

When all the if statements are done checking, you can print the contents of the array.

If there are no items in the result array, you will see you default text "Hello world".

If there are elements in the result array, then you can join the elements in the result array into a string using the array `join()` method.

For example:

```js
var check = 0;
    function numberchecker() {
        var result = [];
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Hello world";
        if ( check > 1 && check < 7 ) { result.push("Check 1");}
        if ( check > 4 && check < 8 ) { result.push("Check 2");}
        if ( check > 6 && check < 10 ) { result.push("Check 3");}
        if (result.length !== 0) {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "True statements: " + result.join();
        }
        console.log(check);
    }

    function addone() {check = check + 1; numberchecker()}
```

```html
<button onclick="addone()">Add One</button>
<p id="container"></p>
```